# XSL to group answers together using MSXML

Tags: javascript, xml, xslt

G'Day all,
Bit stuck over this one as I cannot get the key() to work with my setup..

Ok this ones bulky so bear with me..
What happens is we run from a program, upon triggering the report it will run an HTML file that calls a *.js to load the XML and XSL into the browser (generally Firefox or IE - because of the ActiveX control)

Sample HTML:

```
<html>
  <head>
     <script language="JavaScript" src="Common/Functions.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body onload="displayResult('Common/Hardware.xsl');">
     <div id="report"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Sample JS

```
function loadXMLDoc(dname)
{
  if (window.ActiveXObject)
  {
    xmldom = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM");
    xmldom.async = false;
    xmldom.load(dname);
    return xmldom;
  }
  else
  {
    xhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhttp.open("GET",dname,false);
    xhttp.send("");
    return xhttp.responseXML;
  }
}

function displayResult(stylename)
{
  xml=loadXMLDoc("TempReportData/ExportData.xml");
  xsl=loadXMLDoc(stylename);

  if (window.ActiveXObject)
  {
    document.getElementById("report").innerHTML=xml.transformNode(xsl);
  }
  else
  {
    xsltProcessor=new XSLTProcessor();
    xsltProcessor.importStylesheet(xsl);
    resultDocument = xsltProcessor.transformToFragment(xml,document);
    if (document.getElementById("report").hasChildNodes())
    {
      document.getElementById("report").removeChild(document.getElementById("report").lastChild);
    }
    document.getElementById("report").appendChild(resultDocument);
  }
}
```

Sample XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<Report schema="1.0">
    <Item id="1" name="cabinet">
        <Properties></Properties>
        <VSection>
            <HSection id="60">
                <Component id="1" idfull="00303101">
                    <DisplayName>HardwareHandle</DisplayName>
                    <Category>Hardware</Category>
                    <Brand>CabinetWare</Brand>
                    <Sell>$0.00</Sell>
                    <Quantity>1</Quantity>
                </Component>
            </HSection>
            </VSetion>
        <VSection>
            <HSection id="62">
            </HSection>
        </VSection>
        <VSection>
            <HSection id="205">
                <Component id="1" idfull="003020501">
                    <DisplayName>comment</DisplayName>
                    <Category></Category>
                    <Brand></Brand>
                    <Sell>$0.00</Sell>
                    <Quantity>1</Quantity>
                </Component>
            </HSection>
        </VSection>
    </Item>
</Report>
```

Sample XSL: (included from comment request)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="html" doctype-system="http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd" doctype-public="-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" indent="yes" />

<xsl:key name="Some_Brand" match="Component" select="Brand"/>
<!-- note the moment i ask for this Key the output is blank, if its commented out it below works fine-->

<xsl:template match="/">

<h1>Stock Order Form</h1>

<table>
<tr>
<th>Qty</th>
<th>Part No.</th>
<th>Description</th>
<th>Unit Cost</th>
</tr>
<xsl:apply-templates select="Report/Item"/>
</table>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="Item">
<xsl:apply-templates select="VSection/HSection/Component"/>     
</xsl:template>

<!-- wanting to be able to group items in here, so instead of seeing "1x bolt" and another "1x bolt", i want to see "2x bolt"-->
<xsl:template match="Component">
<xsl:if test="Brand = 'Some_name'">
    <tr>
        <td><xsl:value-of select="Quantity"/></td>
        <td><xsl:value-of select="PartNo"/></td>
        <td><xsl:value-of select="Style"/></td>
        <td><xsl:value-of select="UnitCost"/></td>
    </tr>
</xsl:if>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Please bear in mind this XML above is extremely cut down.. but what i need is to be able to check each item that occurs, and each component within, as they can have several but all at the same level, Report/Item/VSection/HSection/Component, i need to assess that the brand = "Some_name" and return some of the answers contained, ie i might just want the Quantity or Category, of that Component in that Item that matched my Brand i was looking for, and ignore other Components in the same Item that did not.

One of my issues was when i tried to use key() the XSLT just stopped, output was blank. took it away and it worked again, i have a feeling the start of my issue is with the *.js file, or the use of MSXML, as i read somewhere under the Muenchian method that it might not do key()???

Anyway, any suggestions or help, or alternate methods would be great. 
(sorry if my question is vague, let me know and i can edit it, its been a long day)

Alistair.

Comment: It sounds like the issue is more with the XSLT than the javascript, so it would probably be better to show the XSLT in question. Thanks!

Comment: I have heard of and seen certain XSLT implementations that don't support `key()` so that might be what's happening here. Have you tried adding a `try-catch` to your JavaScript to see if the XSLT is producing an error?

Comment: Included the XSL for viewing, note that even though i am not asking for the values contained in the key, the output fails on the simple request of obtaining the key. Excuse my lack of skill in Javascript JLRishe, but where would i include the "try-catch" to test the debug there? i have never really messed with Javascript before (only used what was on hand)

Comment: Hi, the problems you are experiencing, are due to code errors in your XML and XSL (nothing to do with JS). Please start by using a proper XML editor that will show you your errors in the code. For starters, your xml is missing closing tags for `</VSection>` and `</Item>`. Secondly, afaik `<xsl:key` does not have a `select` attribute. Please have a look here - http://www.w3schools.com/xsl/el_key.asp . Please remove HTML/JS from the equation, and try with just the XML/XSL. (Btw, what does your expected output look like?)

Comment: Thanks Nick G - I have amended the XML example, as it was me just cutting and pasting large sections of the original, there is no missing </VSection> or </Item> in my original. BUT i did correct the select="" into a use="" and the output works again, obviously now i can go ahead and use the Muenchian Method to group these results together.

Current Output;
1x Bolt
1x Bolt
1x Screw
1x Nut
1x Nut
1x Nut

Desired Output;
2x Bolt
1x Screw
3x Nut

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned by "Nick G" in the comment, "select" is not a valid attribute on the **xsl:key** statement, it should be **use**

```
<xsl:key name="Some_Brand" match="Component" use="Brand"/>
```

This assumes you are going to be grouping the **Component** elements by their **Brand** value.

In terms of Muenchian grouping, you start off by selecting the **Component** elements who occur first in the key for their given value of **Brand**.

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="VSection/HSection/Component
                             [generate-id() = generate-id(key('Some_Brand', Brand)[1])]"/>
```

Then, within the template that matches **Component**, you can access all elements in the group (i.e. all the **Component** elements with the same **Brand**) by using the key. For example, to sum the total quantity of all items in the group you would do this

```
<xsl:value-of select="sum(key('Some_Brand', Brand)/Quantity)"/>
```

Try this XSLT as a starter:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="html" doctype-system="http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd" doctype-public="-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" indent="yes" />

    <xsl:key name="Some_Brand" match="Component" use="Brand"/>

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <h1>Stock Order Form</h1>
        <table>
            <tr>
                <th>Qty</th>
                <th>Part No.</th>
                <th>Description</th>
            <th>Unit Cost</th>
            </tr>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="Report/Item"/>
        </table>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="Item">
       <xsl:apply-templates select="VSection/HSection/Component[generate-id() = generate-id(key('Some_Brand', Brand)[1])]"/>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="Component">
        <tr>
            <td><xsl:value-of select="Brand"/></td>
            <td><xsl:value-of select="sum(key('Some_Brand', Brand)/Quantity)"/></td>
        </tr>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Hi Tim C, That is brilliant above.. i have made some amendments to the code as i realised that i need to infact filter by the Description of the item and instead just run an IF statement to look at the Brand, so its perfect. i realise this is also very much the "Muenchian Method" as described by Jenni, but was very hard to follow its application in other environments.